# How do I calculate the following limit with L'Hospital?

Tags: limits

I need to find the limit: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x^2+e^{2x})}{\ln(x+e^x)}$$ How do I do it with L'Hospital?

Comment: Really? You don't know how to apply L'Hopital?

Comment: I know how but I just applied it like 3 times and I still get $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: @OvyOvy One time is enough.

Comment: Am I missing something then? Cause if you apply it one time you get $\frac{(2x+2e^{2x})(x+e^x)}{(x^2+e^{2x})(1+e^x)}$

Comment: @OvyOvy Remember that $\lim_{x \to \infty} x / e^x = 0\,$.

Comment: @dxiv You can get that by applying L'Hôpital twice more - maybe that's where the "three times" came from :P

Comment: Much more natural than L'Hopital would be to rewrite this as $$\frac{2+x^{-1}\log(1+(xe^{-x})^2)}{1+\ln(1+xe^{-x})}$$

Comment: @Did Could you show how you arrived at that expression?

Comment: @mrnovice Try the intermediary step $$\frac{2x+\log(1+x^2e^{-2x})}{x+\log(1+xe^{-x})}$$ which leads to $$\frac{2+x^{-1}\log(1+(xe^{-x})^2)}{1+x^{-1}\log(1+xe^{-x})}$$ and use that $$xe^{-x}\to0$$ hence $$\log(1+(xe^{-x})^2)\to0$$ and $$\log(1+xe^{-x})\to0$$ (Yes, typo in my first comment, a factor $x^{-1}$ is missing from the denominator.)

Comment: @Did My confusion stems from the first step in your previous comment, where do the $2x+$ and $x+$ in the numerator and denominator respectively come from?

Comment: @mrnovice For example, $\log(x+e^x)=\log(e^x(1+xe^{-x}))=x+\log(1+xe^{-x})$.

Comment: @Did Thanks, I understand now

Answer (score 4):

Hint: This is one where you learn a lot more without L'Hopital: Note that for large $x, x^2 < e^{2x}.$ Thus $e^{2x} < x^2+e^{2x} < 2e^{2x}$ for large $x.$ Similarly, $e^x < x + e^x < 2e^x.$ If you use these estimates, you can bound the expression below and above with functions that have the same limit.

Comment: Technically speaking, this is off-topic since the OP specifies that one should use L'H, but mathematically speaking, this is sooo much more interesting / enlightening / simple than L'H... In the end, +1, because mathematics should win.

Comment: @Did I hadn't absorbed the fact that the OP was specifying L'H, but I see it now. Thanks for the comment and well put.

Answer (score 2):

First you should verify the hypotheses of l'Hopital's rule.

Then, actually using the rule, you get:

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\ln(x^2 + e^{2x})}{\ln(x+e^x)} = \lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{\frac1{x^2+e^{2x}} \cdot (2x + 2e^{2x})}{\frac1{x+e^x}\cdot (1 + e^x)} = \lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{2(x+e^{2x})(x+e^x)}{(x^2+e^{2x})(1+e^x)}$$

At this point I suggest the following steps.

1. Expand (FOIL) in the numerator and denominator.  (This step may not actually be necessary but it's how I'd do it on a "first draft" I suppose.)
2. Divide the entire numerator and denominator by $e^{3x}$ (because that's the dominating term in both).
3. Evaluate the limit with direct substitution.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  } \frac { \ln(x^{ 2 }+e^{ 2x }) }{ \ln(x+e^{ x }) } \overset { L'Hospital }{ = } \lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  } \frac { \frac { 2x+2{ e }^{ 2x } }{ { x }^{ 2 }+{ e }^{ 2x } }  }{ \frac { 1+{ e }^{ x } }{ x+{ e }^{ x } }  } =2\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  } \frac { \left( x+{ e }^{ 2x } \right) \left( x+{ e }^{ x } \right)  }{ \left( { x }^{ 2 }+{ e }^{ 2x } \right) \left( 1+{ e }^{ x } \right)  } =\\ =2\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  } \frac { { e }^{ 3x }\left( \frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ { { e }^{ 3x } } } +\frac { x }{ { e }^{ 2x } } +\frac { x }{ { e }^{ x } } +1 \right)  }{ { e }^{ 3x }\left( \frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ { { e }^{ 3x } } } +\frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ { e }^{ 2x } } +\frac { 1 }{ { e }^{ x } } +1 \right)  } =2$$

Answer (score 1):

First we have the intuitive version which is useful when you get such problems in a competitive objective type test. As $x \to \infty$ the terms $x, x^{2}$ can be ignored safely and only the exponential terms matter. Thus the expression in the question is roughly equal to $(\log e^{2x})/\log e^{x} = 2x/x = 2$ and hence the desired limit is $2$.

The rigorous version tells us *why we can ignore terms $x, x^{2}$ safely*. We have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log(x^{2} + e^{2x})}{\log(x + e^{x})}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log e^{2x}(1 + x^{2}e^{-2x})}{\log e^{x}(1 + xe^{-x})}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{2x + \log(1 + x^{2}e^{-2x})}{x + \log(1 + xe^{-x})}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{2 + \dfrac{\log(1 + x^{2}e^{-2x})}{x}}{1 + \dfrac{\log(1 + xe^{-x})}{x}}\notag\\
&= \frac{2 + 0}{1 + 0} = 2\notag
\end{align}
In the last step we use the fact that $\lim_{x \to \infty}x^{n}e^{-x} = 0$ for any $n$ (this can be proved in many ways including the use of L'Hospital's Rule which you can try yourself) so that $x^{2}e^{-2x} \to 0, xe^{-x} \to 0$. This means that $\log(1 + x^{2}e^{-2x}) \to 0, \log(1 + xe^{-x}) \to 0$ and we are done.

Note that terms like $x, x^{2}$ can not be ignored safely in all contexts, hence the intuitive reasoning must always be backed by rigor. With reasonable experience in these matters one can just have a glance at the expression and tell which terms to keep and which ones to ignore. But unless one attains that level of maturity it is best to stick to the rigorous version.